# In LaTeX, can I access the contents of a hyperref TextField and display them below, marked up in math mode?

Tags: equations, hyperref, calc

It's fairly easy to set up a fillable field. How can I access the contents of that field and display them, marked up using math mode?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{calc}

\def\equationEntry#1#2{%
    \TextField[name=#1, width=0.5\textwidth]{#2}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{Form}
    \equationEntry{inputEquation1}{Enter an equation : }

    % TODO display the contents of the field above, marked up using math mode
\end{Form}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand: You expect that an equation typed into a pdf form is run by TeX and displayed?

Answer (score 1):

Conceptually this is not really feasible. LaTeX compiles the source code of your form (i.e., the code you show in the question) into a pdf, and afterwards LaTeX is not involved anymore in anything that happens to the pdf.

If the pdf viewer allows you to execute Javascript (many viewers don't allow this, but some do) you can make the form interactive, but only to execute Javascript, which makes it impossible to call LaTeX (or other external programs) and/or actually collect the result of a LaTeX run and properly show it in the pdf. And even if this was possible then still the user opening the form should have LaTeX installed or you should setup access to a web service somehow, which is also not trivial.

It *might* be a possibility to run MathJax inside a pdf, because MathJax is a Javascript library. MathJax has a syntax and output similar to (but much more limited than) LaTeX. However, I would be surprised if this could be made to actually work (and I could find no such attempts with a quick web search), because MathJax is intended to produce output on web pages and not in a pdf.

This may lead you to an alternative, which is to make a web application instead of a pdf form. Then of course you can't use LaTeX for typesetting anymore (or you need a converter from LaTeX to web, which does not always produce nice results) but you gain a lot of interactivity and flexibility.